# Can't see any custom fields when 'adding new item' to custom list

Tags: development, custom-list, list-definition, custom-field-types

As title says, I can only see the 'Title' field when adding a new item to my custom list.

Any ideas?

I've double checked the field definitions and checked the field references are in both default views. No problems there.

I can create the list using the definitions, and I can add new list items, and the custom fields are disblayed in the list table and in list settings - but not in the 'Add New Item' dialog.

**EDIT: I think this may be because my custom list definitions are inheriting from the 'Item' content type if this is of any use to anyone about to suggest an answer!?**

Comment: How are you creating the custom fields? Xml Feature Definitions? Code? Through the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave this question posted here because the solution doesn't appear to be documented much.

http://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/sharepoint-2010-list-fields-not-showing-up-in-edit-display-or-new-forms/

^ That page addressed my exact problem.

The solution being:

**"Remove the content type reference from the markup..."**